# Database doesn't like reading values from a loop

Tags: java

I have a java database successfully connected to my java code. Thats all fine as it works and all.

When I store a result from the database into a variable ... it works perfectly.

Now as I have to do this 8 times I used a loop and a array however by using a try catch tool it gives out a error of, Error is: java.lang.NullPointerException

Futher investigation shows that it seems to not like the loop strangely.

```
public String Title []; //in class but out of any methods
    public void gettinginfo ()
    {
        try
        {
            int AB = 0;  //array base starts from 0
            //ID in database starts from 1
            for (int i = 1; i<=8; i++)
            {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE ID = " + i;
                Rs = St.executeQuery(query);
                while (Rs.next())
                {   
                    Title[AB] = Rs.getString("StudentName");
                    AB++;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error is: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you instantiated your statement object?

Comment: System.out.println("Error is: " + ex); >> Just no. Replace that with ex.printStackTrace, or even better, remove that catch Exception. Also in Java variable names start with lowercase.

Comment: I think it might have more to do with your `Title` array...

Comment: We can just guess as long as he doesn't post the stacktrace.

Comment: Make sure that `Title` array and `Statement` objects are and not null

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't have ResultSet and Statement as class members unless you have a strong reason to do so.

Comment: I tried adding this: System.out.println("Error is: " + ex.printStackTrace); but it comes with a error of cannot be resolved or not named in a field

Comment: Just say ex.printStackTrace(); in catch block

Comment: or `throw new RuntimeException(ex)`, which is what I would write. I don't see any pressure to swallow the exception within this method.

Comment: @Bobski Are you sure you want to use `for` loop? You can achieve with out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What line is your NullPointerException occurring on?  Likely your `Title` array has not been initialized.  If you know how many rows the query will return, you can say:

```
Title = new String[numRows];
```

But if you don't, you'll need to either run a `SELECT count(*) ...` query or use an `ArrayList` or other resizable list, instead of an array.

---

Your code is also very poorly structured, which is no small part of why you're having trouble debugging this.  I've cleaned up your code below, with comments explaining my changes:

```
public class YourClass
{
  private static final int MAX_ID = 8; // or however you want to set the size
  private String[] title; // [] after the type is easier to read, lower case variables
  private Connection conn; // I'm assuming the class will be provided a DB connection
  // Note the Statement and ResultSet objects are not defined in the class, to
  // minimize their scope.

  public void queryInfo() // name suggests a query (potentially expensive) will be run
  {
    title = new String[MAX_ID]; // **initialize title**
    // We use a try-with-resources block to ensure the statement is safely closed
    // even better would be to use a PreparedStatement here
    try(Statement st = conn.statement())
    {
      // You're executing 8 separate queries here, where one will do
      String query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE ID >= 1 AND ID <= "+MAX_ID;
      // Again, we need to close the result set when we're done
      try(ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query))
      {
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next())
        {   
          title[i++] = rs.getString("StudentName");
        }
      } // close our ResultSet
    } // close our Statement
  }

  // provide a separate getter method, rather than making the array public
  public String[] getTitles()
  {
    return title;
  }
}
```

There's still more that could be improved - using an array seems like a poor design, as does calling a method which populates a class variable rather than simply having `queryInfo()` return a new array.  You can also look into using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).  Hopefully these suggestions help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Title` array and `Statement St` objects are and not null. These are the only two reasons that I suspect. Give FULL stacktrace if it doesn't work.

`Title` array is NULL. "new" this array to the size equal to number of rows. If you don't know the rows, fire a `count(*) query first`, find out the no of rows and then intantiate `Title` array or use `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String` array.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have not initialized your Title array, you have to set it equal to something or it will just be null which will cause a nullPointerException, but as others have stated there is no way to be sure since your haven't given us a full stack trace or even the line number of the exception. In this case the exception should be handled as such:

```
try{
    //your code here
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code will give you the full stack trace making it much easier to track down the issue.
Also you may want to consider using an ArrayList instead of an array:

```
List<String> Title = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then to add to it:

```
Title.add(Rs.getString("StudentName"));
```

If you need it as an array later then:

```
String[] title = Title.toArray(new String[Title.size()]);
```

You can read more about ArrayLists [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)